# Unable to put value using :value wiht v-model together in VueJS 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In a page i am fetcing data from API and showing the data in the text field. After that user can change the data and submit the form. I am uanble to show data using :value in the inout field. Its showing `conflicts with v-model on the same element because the latter already expands to a value binding internally`

I tried  to mount the data after it loads. But it is still not showing.

```
    <input v-model="password" :value="credentials.password">

  created() {
      let txid = this.$route.params.id
      this.$axios.get(this.$axios.defaults.baseURL+'/v1/purno/internal/users/'+ txid, {
      }).then((response) => {
        if (response.data.status == 'error') {
          toast.$toast.error('Something Went Wrong at!', {
            // override the global option
            position: 'top'
          })
        } else if (response.data.status == 'success') {
          if(response.data.data.found ==true) {
            this.credentials = response.data.data;
          })
          }
        }

      })
      });

    },
  data(){
    return {
      credentials:[],
      password:null
    

    }
  },
  mounted(){
  this.password = this.credentials.password
  }
```

How can i solve this problem? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please complete it within the request callback

```
this.credentials = response.data.data; 
this.password = this.credentials.password;
```

like this in the then callback fn. Try it!

Comment: Can u pls expand your answer?

Comment: this.credentials = response.data.data; this.password = this.credentials.password; like this in the then callback fn. Try it!

Comment: No response data when the mount hook is invoked. So make sure assignment operation after the response.

Answer (score 0):

`conflicts with v-model on the same element because the latter already expands to a value binding internally` error message tells it all

`v-model="password"` is same as `:value="password" @input="password = $event.target.value"` (for text and textarea - see [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Basic-Usage))

So using it together with another `:value` makes no sense...